# Setting up Parse with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform, gradle

I am pretty new to the whole android coding thing. I have been using the New Boston YouTube series and have learnt how to code an app using eclipse.

I now want to use Parse to create a database behind my application. However when I have tried to set it up, it says I need to insert code into the build.gradle as I am not using android studio and just Java in eclipse with the relevant plug ins I don't have this.

I have tried doing everything but including the instructions for the gradle bit  but it just crashes the application.

Do you know if you can use Parse if you are not using android studio? I have downloaded the gradle plug in but it seems like you can only make a new project? is there a way of linking it to an existing project?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Use Android Studio, remove the horrific devil known as Eclipse.  Get [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

please use this link to get the .jar file:  [jar download](https://parse.com/docs/downloads)
choose Android, 
add the downloaded **Parse-1.10.3.jar** file to your **libs** folder, also don't forget toadd the jar file to projects **buildpath**

everything else is similar... hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I have downloaded those jars and added them to relevant folders and buildpath. Then each time I add in their code to test it, it completely crashes my app... any ideas? I thought it was because I didn't/couldn't do the build.gradle

Comment: sory.. i didnt get what is ur exact problem now!